# Remove "hello world" from default empty project

Tags: android-studio

I want to change the default empty project to remove Hello World so it doesnt appear in new empty project. Tried a few suggestions but couldn't find what people were saying to look for and edit. Just not there.
I don't want to see hello world on every project

Answer (score 0):

Go to /app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml

Delete this

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

or
switch to design and delete TextView in the component tree